# Sound card module no longer loading on boot

Tags: 20.04, sound

I have a laptop running 20.04, which I update almost every day. At some point recently I noticed that sound no longer works. I have tracked this down to the appropriate module not being loaded on boot. If I run the following command, then sound works:

```
sudo modprobe snd_hda_intel
```

I suspect this may be because my HDMI hardware has audio functionality, in addition to having a "sound card".

```
stan@yogi:~/bin$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
```

Does anyone have an idea where to go next on troubleshooting and fixing this?